# NSDateComponentFormatter: keep all zeroes for all units

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I'm using a NSDateComponentFormatter to print durations, like so:

```
/// Hour-Minute duration formatter (abbreviated, localized, eg. 6h 22m)
    let hourMinuteDurationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
        dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
        dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
        return dateComponentsFormatter
    }()
```

This works fine in most of the cases.
For example, I can print duration strings like "6h 56mn"

However, if the number of minutes is less than 10, I get this kind of strings: "6h 3mn"
As I'm using these duration strings in a table, I'd like them to be formatted consistently, that is, keeping all zeroes.
For instance, I'd like to have "6h 03mn".

NB: Yes, NSDateFormatter has a dateFormat property to format dates/time like "HH:mm" or "HH'h 'mm'mn' ", but it doesn't work with durations.
And I haven't found a formatter for durations except NSDateComponentsFormatter.

Thanks

Comment: NSDateComponentsFormatter has a lot of parameters, so maybe someone knows one that could help me. The fact that I haven't found it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: The `zeroFormattingBehavior` is not the formatting of leading zeros in a non-zero number, but rather what to do if the value is exactly zero (e.g. `6h 0m` vs just `6h`). You can always request an enhancement for this if you want, but I'm not sure there's enough people who need that behavior to justify the enhancement. But you can make the request and see what they say. Perhaps something equivalent to `formatString` and `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` of `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: FWIW, while I know it's not what you're looking for,  `.positional` will include the leading zeros

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the tips. I'd like to use `.positional`, but the separator between units is `:`. And the designers don't want to display the full duration (HH:mm:ss), so for example, if I display "6:00", the user wouldn't know if it's 6 minutes 0 seconds, or 6 hours 0 minutes ...

Comment: Keep in mind that this design may have localization issues. A major point of `NSDateComponentFormatter` is to format dates in locale-sensitive ways, and a leading 0 (or ٠ or ༠ or the half-dozen other versions of zero) may not be acceptable in all locales. If your design relies on a very precise layout, you should likely just format it yourself by hand (recognizing that this may cause localization issues) or reconsider your design. (Even .positional doesn't promise that it'll be a fixed width, just that it "uses the position of a unit to identify its value.")

Comment: But is there the equivalent of NSDateFormatter for durations? Working with NSTimeInterval?

Comment: There's `NSTimeIntervalFormatter`, but that's even further from what you're looking for. Apple just doesn't show intervals in the form of `6h 05m`. You'll either have to push back on your designers to use one of the available standard formats or write your own routine.

Comment: I can't find a NSTimeIntervalFormatter in Foundation. There is a NSDateIntervalFormatter though, but it's designed for intervals of dates (like from Aug 1st to 1Aug 8th). There is also a custom built TimeIntervalFormatter here but i's not Apple-made. https://github.com/RLovelett/NSTimeIntervalFormatter/tree/master/NSTimeIntervalFormatter

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to `NSDateIntervalFormatter`. It's academic, as it's not going to do what you're looking for. Again, change the expectations on the design or roll your own...

Comment: All right, thanks for the infos!